# SVG support on smart-phone browsers

Tags: android, ios, html, svg, mobile-website

I am investigating SVG, so I was wondering if anyone knows how good SVG support is for browsers on smart-phones. I know Opera Mini/iPhone support a lot of SVG Tiny, but I cannot figure out the support for other browsers (Blackberry, Pre, Android, Nokia smart-phones). I know phones using IE as rendering engine will have no support at all.

I have tried to find latest data, but cannot find anything later than 2007. I would appreciate if anyone can link to a post that discusses SVG support on mobile browsers.

Comment: Looks like now days it works everywhere: http://caniuse.com/svg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Information about this topic really is rare (but that's nothing new when we talk about SVG, unfortunately...)

There are a few test results from the Tiny Test Suite available (end of 2008):
http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.2/Tiny/ImpReport.html
BitFlash, eSVG, Ikivo and Motorola SVG are of special interest here. Opera Mobile is not covered by this test but it uses Ikivo as far as I know.

And there is a pretty current discussion here:
http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/svg-developers/message/63147
Until now the results of this discussion are rather poor, but maybe you can join in there...

However, considering the pain (native) SVG development causes with "desktop browsers" I would not really recommend it for mobile browsers unless you have a very specific target group (with SVG enabled devices) or other serious reasons to use SVG.

I'm sorry that I couldn't contribute more, maybe it was a little help anyway.

Answer (score 4):

As for today (Jan 2013) it looks like SVG is supported in the most popular desktop and mobile browsers - on their latest versions:

- IE
- Firefox Chrome
- Safari
- Opera
- iOS Safari
- Opera Mini
- Android Browser
- Blackberry Browser
- Opera Mobile
- Chrome for Android
- Firefox for Android

Source: [caniuse.com/svg](http://caniuse.com/svg)

Comment: Confirming BlackBerry support. Even as old as BlackBerry OS 6 supports SVG image perfectly. http://i.imgur.com/iXtUBnm.png SVG animation is little imperfect but it does its job. https://gfycat.com/GrandSimplisticCranefly

Answer (score 1):

Supported browsers:
iOS 5+
Android 3+

Source: http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-html5

Answer (score 0):

Currently some people including me work on it independently.
You may find working solution in these articles:
  [Android. ImageView with SVG Support.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidImageViewSVG.aspx)
  [Android ImageView and Drawable with SVG support](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/Android_SVG_support.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

BlackBerry [actually supports SVG animation](https://gfycat.com/GrandSimplisticCranefly) as far as OS 6, albeit imperfectly.

The same OS 6 also [supports SVG image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBb3o.png) with no problem of resizing.